# Python get number of pages from password protected pdf

Tags: python, pdf, encryption

I've been trying to figure out a way to get the number of pages from password protected PDF with Python 3. So far I have tried modules pypdf and pdfminer2.
Both are failing because the file is not decrypted.

```
from pypdf import PdfReader
reader = PdfReader("encrypted.pdf")
print(len(reader.pages))
```

This code will produce an **Error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pypdf/_page.py", line 2155, in __len__
    return self.length_function()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pypdf/_reader.py", line 449, in _get_num_pages
    return self.trailer[TK.ROOT]["/Pages"]["/Count"]  # type: ignore
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^
  File "pypdf/generic/_data_structures.py", line 291, in __getitem__
    return dict.__getitem__(self, key).get_object()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pypdf/generic/_base.py", line 290, in get_object
    obj = self.pdf.get_object(self)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pypdf/_reader.py", line 1359, in get_object
    raise FileNotDecryptedError("File has not been decrypted")
pypdf.errors.FileNotDecryptedError: File has not been decrypted
```

Is there a way to get the number of pages without decrypting?

Comment: this can help https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/51

Comment: Empty password leads to following Error: NotImplementedError: only algorithm code 1 and 2 are supported

Comment: In  pdfReader.decrypt('password')  line  provide correct password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **pdfrw**

**Example**,

**a.pdf** and **b.pdf** are same pdf. Difference is **b.pdf** is **password protected pdf** and **a.pdf** is simple pdf **without any  protection** and no of pages are 30

```
>>> from pdfrw import PdfReader
>>> print len(PdfReader('b.pdf').pages)
30
>>> print len(PdfReader('a.pdf').pages)
30
```

For install use following command

```
pip install pdfrw
```

For in detail **[PDFRW](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfrw)**

Comment: Thanks. This approach seems to work for lightly secured documents (no password, some restrictions), but not for heavily secured (password protected and only printing allowed).

Comment: @JBeardie what you mean by "not for heavily secured ".   and feel free to upvote if it's works for you

Comment: @JBeardie In the example,  b.pdf is password protected and I can get no of pages. If you getting error while running with password protected file then show me the error

Comment: I think the problem is with compressing: There are many lines of Errors: [ERROR] uncompress.py:72 Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check (2947, 0) .. I tried to open this cocument in PDFtk, but it prompts a password.

Comment: You can try this document: https://www.yokogawa.com/an/download/general/GS11M12A01-01E.pdf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152506/discussion-between-jbeardie-and-kallz).

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
from pypdf import PdfReader
reader = PdfReader('path/to/file.pdf')
reader.decrypt(password)
print(len(reader.pages))
```

I would recommend removing the read-protection with a command-line tool such as qpdf (easily installable, e.g. on Ubuntu use `apt-get install qpdf` if you don't have it already):

`qpdf --password=PASSWORD --decrypt SECURED.pdf UNSECURED.pdf`
Then open the unlocked file with `pdfminer` and do your stuff.

Comment: Did you test it with password protected pdf?

Comment: There is no way around. You need to decrypt the pdf before getting the number of pages.

    `pdf.decrypt(password)`

Comment: Ok. I wonder how the pdf reader-applications manage to do it, but not python?

Comment: I would recommend removing the read-protection with a command-line tool such as qpdf (easily installable, e.g. on Ubuntu use `apt-get install qpdf` if you don't have it already):

`qpdf --password=PASSWORD --decrypt SECURED.pdf UNSECURED.pdf`
Then open the unlocked file with `pdfminer` and do your stuff.