# Getting password protected PDF total page numbers into excel

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I have a list of PDF files saved in a folder, and I am trying to get the total page number of each PDF file and save it to an excel spreadsheet.

The code works fine with normal PDF files, but the code would not work and return total page number = 0 when the PDFs is password protected, does anyone know how to get around this?

```
Option Explicit
Public Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Public Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
 
Public Function ClearClipboard()
    OpenClipboard (0&)
    EmptyClipboard
    CloseClipboard
End Function
 

Sub CountPages()
    Dim MyPath As String, MyFile As String
    Dim i As Long
    MyPath = Cells(1, 7)
    MyFile = Dir(MyPath & Application.PathSeparator & "*.pdf", vbDirectory)
    Range("A:B").ClearContents
    Range("A1") = "File Name": Range("B1") = "Pages"
    Range("A1:B1").Font.Bold = True
    i = 1
    Do While MyFile <> ""
        i = i + 1
        Cells(i, 1) = MyFile
        Cells(i, 2) = GetPageNum(MyPath & Application.PathSeparator & MyFile)
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop
    Columns("A:B").AutoFit
    MsgBox "Total of " & i - 1 & " PDF files have been found" & vbCrLf _
           & " File names and corresponding count of pages have been written on " _
           & ActiveSheet.Name, vbInformation, "Report..."
End Sub



Function GetPageNum(PDF_File As String)
    Dim FileNum As Long
    Dim strRetVal As String
    Dim RegExp
    Set RegExp = CreateObject("VBscript.RegExp")
    RegExp.Global = True
    RegExp.Pattern = "/Type\s*/Page[^s]"
    FileNum = FreeFile
    Open PDF_File For Binary As #FileNum
        strRetVal = Space(LOF(FileNum))
        Get #FileNum, , strRetVal
    Close #FileNum
    GetPageNum = RegExp.Execute(strRetVal).Count
End Function
```

---

Comment: Since your code opens each PDF, logic would suggest that in order to open password protected PDFs, you would need to provide the password.

Comment: so is your question really "how do i read a password protected pdf?" that's simple... you just use the password.

Comment: This had been asked already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48484855/excel-vba-to-return-page-count-from-protected-pdf-file but I don't see any answer that could help you...

Comment: Thanks all for the input.  I do have the passwords to the pdfs, any suggestions on how i need to change for the code to open the pdf files?

Comment: Unless you have full control over your PDF environment (meaning, they are created under your full control), using a regular expression text search to find the number of pages is a very bad idea. The reason it doesn't work for password protected files is that normally those are encrypted. But there are plenty of ways other files might fail in your implementation as well.